# Upload file from AngularJS to Spring Boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, file, http, request

I'm using AngularJS to make my front end and Java with Spring Boot to make my back end. I'm trying to import/upload a xlsx, xls, or ods file from the Angular to my Java, but whatever I do, the request doesn't send my file!

Java endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload/{type}")
@ResponseBody
private ResponseEntity<List<Rota>> importFile(@PathVariable("type") String type,
                                              @RequestParam(required = false, value = "file") MultipartFile fileParam, 
                                              @RequestBody MultipartFile  file) {
    System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());
    if(type.toUpperCase().equals("XLSX")){
        System.out.println("XLSX!");
    }else if(type.toUpperCase().equals("XLS")){
        System.out.println("XLS!");
    }else if(type.toUpperCase().equals("ODS")){
        System.out.println("ODS!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("OPS!");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ArrayList<>(), HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ArrayList<>(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

My request-id made using an Angular class prepared to only make requests. I'll post here the code that we use normally in the project and the code that actually worked but I can't use it.

DataFactory:

```
DataFactory.POST = function (url, entity, config = null) {
  if (url && entity) {
    return $http
      .post(url, entity, config)
      .then(res => $q.resolve(res.data), error => $q.reject(error));
  }
};
```

The code that actually worked:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('POST', `${URL.CTM_ODS()}/rotas/upload/${type}`, true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

When I use Postman, sending the file through the body, the back end receives null, but when I use form-data from Postman, works fine!
Using the DataFactory I got the following stack on my back end:

```
WARN 16796 --- [p1002886236-126] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser        : badMessage: java.lang.IllegalStateException: too much data after closed for HttpChannelOverHttp@78fd8670{r=2,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLHgpOG1cW4
My problem was that the AngularJS deserialize the file! So, what I've made was just put a config object saying to not do that:

```
DataFactory.POST(`${URL.CTM_ODS()}/rotas/upload/${type}`, formData, { transformRequest: angular.indentity, headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined } }).then(response => {
    delete vm.importacao.arquivoCsv;
    console.log('Response: ', response);
    LoadingManager.hide();
  });
```

As you can see, the difference is on the header object, can you see that we pass the content type as undefined and `transformRequest: angular.indentity`? That worked for me! If anyone has other way to do so, feel free to comment! Thanks and have a nice day!